# Excel AutoFilter range set by combo boxes?

Tags: excel, filter, combobox, vba

I am currently working on a bear of a worksheet that is designed to show the change of individual parameters over the same time interval using the Backdoor technique detailed at http://peltiertech.com/excel/chartshowto/panelunevenscales.html.

Basically, I have it set up as a template where 5 columns of data (which vary in length of rows) can be pasted into columns A-F starting at row 12. The time column that I would like to filter is in column A and I basically want to make it so that 2 combo boxes (ComboBox1 and ComboBox2) can be used to set an upper and lower time limit and filter out any other data. I'm hoping I can turn this into a dynamic chart that will resize the x-axis to show only the selected time period.

I'm still relatively new to using VBA and I did a good bit of searching and the only thing I could find that seemed related was the question answered at http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=54376. I tried the following code and kept getting errors:

```
Sub TimeFilter()

Crit1 = Format(ComboBox1, "0")

Crit2 = Format(ComboBox2, "0")

.AutoFilterMode = False

.Range("A12:L10000").AutoFilter

.Range("A12:L10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:=">=" & crit1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & crit2

End Sub
```

Any ideas on why it might not be working? Any help or guidance is appreciated!

****EDIT****

Here is the updated FULL code for the spreadsheet I'm using, and with the TimeFilter script I get a "Run-time error '1004', AutoFilter method of Range class failed":
**The time that I am filtering by is in 0.2 second intervals with the format MM:SS.X.

```
Sub CreateComboBoxes()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set Cell = Range("I8")  
    With Cell
        sht.DropDowns.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height).Name = "ComboBox1"
    End With

    Set Cell = Range("K8")    
    With Cell
        sht.DropDowns.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height).Name = "ComboBox2"
    End With

End Sub

Sub TimeFilter()

Crit1 = Format(ComboBox1, "0")
Crit2 = Format(ComboBox2, "0")

Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A12:L10000").AutoFilter
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A12:L10000").AutoFilter Field:=1,Criteria1:=">=" & Crit1, Operator:=xlAnd, _
Criteria2:="<=" & Crit2

End Sub
```

Comment: If you use `Option Explicit` and define `Crit1` and `Crit2` as specific variable types ... maybe `Date` or `Double`, you're filter should work then, provided that the cells in column A are in `Date/Time` format. [This may help](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-dates.htm) ... but there is something better ... there's a `FilterByDate` option as well, but I can't find any reference to it at the moment. If you record a macro, you will get the right code for it.

Comment: You need to qualify your objects. E.g. `.AutoFilterMode = False` should be something like `Worksheets("Sheet1").AutofilterMode = False`

Comment: What errors are you getting, I'm running the code as presented except the input is a date string "01/01/05" and "31/12/10" instead of ComboBox1 and -2 respectively. The data in my table consists of 300 rows of dates between today's date and "01/01/01" The code runs without issues and the result is as expected. Sidenote: I'm assuming this is just a snippet and the `With ...`, `End With` is outside of this code snippet which for the purpose of testing I've included.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses. As I said, I'm still pretty new to the whole VBA game and while I have gotten decent at interpreting existing code and following the flow, I'm not so great at writing my own detailed code yet. I've edited my original post to show full code that I am using for this workbook including the macro for creating the comboboxes. @SilentRevolution, if there should be "With" and "End With" statements along with this code, can you point me in the direction of where they should be located?

Comment: Also, should the script for creating the comboboxes be combined with the script for the filter, or kept separate? And finally, should this code be used in the VBA repository for the whole workbook or coded in the individual sheet code? Sorry for all of the questions, but I just want to make sure I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I preface this by stating that this is not an answer but an explanation in the use of `With`, `End With` statement. The comment section does not offer the formatting tools required to do so properly

The `With`, `End With` statements save you on typing the same bits over and over.

```
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Font.ColorIndex = 3
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Font.Bold = True
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Font.Size = 15
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Font.Name = "Times new Roman"
```

Can also be written as

```
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Font
        .ColorIndex = 3
        .Bold = True
        .Size = 15
        .Name = "Times new Roman"
    End With
```

You'll notice the "." in front of the lines in between the with end with statement, this means it should be read as a continuation of what is set by the `With` statement.